# In the CurrencyConverter Ubuntu SDK QML example where does the index variable come from?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

In Ubuntu SDK [QML tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/tutorial/building_your_first_qml_app/) a simple currency converter is build. The complete QML source code can be found [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-tutorials-dev/ubuntu-sdk-tutorials/trunk/view/head:/getting-started/CurrencyConverter/CurrencyConverter.qml). When working through the example I found the following snippet somewhat confusing, particularly line 92 where the index field is assigned to `caller.currencyIndex`.

```
ListView {
    clip: true
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height - header.height
    model: currencies
    delegate: Standard {
        objectName: "popoverCurrencySelector"
        text: currency
        onClicked: {
            caller.currencyIndex = index // where does index come from?
            caller.input.update()
            hide()
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any clue in the documentation where `index` is defined. What it should contain is absolutely obvious, but where does it come from? If it is a property of the `Standard` list view item it is nowhere documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` is a property of the ListView delegate, not necessarily a ListItem. It represents the number of the `currentItem`. [From the docs:](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-listview.html#delegate-prop)

> The index is exposed as an accessible index property. Properties of the model are also available depending upon the type of Data Model.

Comment: That was exactly the piece of documentation I was looking for! Would've never expected this to be a property of the delegate.